# How to determine Windows version in future-proof way

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I noticed that [`GetVersionEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724451(v=vs.85).aspx) is declared deprecated.  Worse yet, for Windows 8.1 (and presumably future releases) the version number is limited by the application manifest.

My goal is to collect analytics on operating systems which the users are running, so I can appropriately target support.  I would like a future-proof solution for collecting this data.  Updating the manifest won't work because I can only update the manifest for Windows versions which have already been released, not for future versions.  The suggested replacement API, the [version helper functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn424972(v=vs.85).aspx), is useless.

How can I collect the actual Windows version number?

To clarify: By "future proofing", I just mean that I want something that has a reasonably good chance of working on the next version of Windows.  Nothing is certain, but the docs do say that `GetVersionEx()` won't work.

Comment: What am I missing? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724429(v=vs.85).aspx *To obtain the full version number for the operating system, call the GetFileVersionInfo function on one of the system DLLs, such as Kernel32.dll, then call VerQueryValue to obtain the \\StringFileInfo\\<lang><codepage>\\ProductVersion subblock of the file version information.*

Comment: @ta.speot.is I was just about to copy and paste this into an answer. OP: have you tried the above method?

Comment: Part of the reason why the version helper functions exist and the `GetVersion()` API is deprecated is because [many people fail to correctly implement version number checking routines](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/13/72476.aspx). In your case, however, you may go with [the method suggested by ta.speot.is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25986331/how-to-determine-windows-version-in-future-proof-way#comment40693296_25986331) to obtain some kind of versioning information.

Comment: @ta.speot.is: That looks like an answer, but you have posted it as a comment.

Comment: Microsoft approach to deprecation seems like a bad joke. "many people are using this function incorrectly, therefore we will make it lie depending on which OS version the code is running".

Comment: Also, annoying thing with the version helper functions is that they require manifest to explicitly declare that the executable is compatible with an os version. Otherwise IsWindows10OrGreater and  IsWindows8Point1OrGreater will return false even if run on Windows 10.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

MSDN has [an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724429(v=vs.85).aspx) showing how to use the (useless for your scenario) version helper functions, but in the introduction is the following:

> To obtain the full version number for the operating system, call the GetFileVersionInfo function on one of the system DLLs, such as Kernel32.dll, then call VerQueryValue to obtain the \StringFileInfo\\ProductVersion subblock of the file version information.

As of right now, neither the `GetFileVersionInfo` nor `VerQueryValue` function are deprecated.

### Example

This will extract the product version from `kernel32.dll` and print it to the console:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "version.lib")

static const wchar_t kernel32[] = L"\\kernel32.dll";
wchar_t *path = NULL;
void *ver = NULL, *block;
UINT n;
BOOL r;
DWORD versz, blocksz;
VS_FIXEDFILEINFO *vinfo;

path = malloc(sizeof(*path) * MAX_PATH);
if (!path)
    abort();

n = GetSystemDirectory(path, MAX_PATH);
if (n >= MAX_PATH || n == 0 ||
    n > MAX_PATH - sizeof(kernel32) / sizeof(*kernel32))
    abort();
memcpy(path + n, kernel32, sizeof(kernel32));

versz = GetFileVersionInfoSize(path, NULL);
if (versz == 0)
    abort();
ver = malloc(versz);
if (!ver)
    abort();
r = GetFileVersionInfo(path, 0, versz, ver);
if (!r)
    abort();
r = VerQueryValue(ver, L"\\", &block, &blocksz);
if (!r || blocksz < sizeof(VS_FIXEDFILEINFO))
    abort();
vinfo = (VS_FIXEDFILEINFO *) block;
printf(
    "Windows version: %d.%d.%d",
    (int) HIWORD(vinfo->dwProductVersionMS),
    (int) LOWORD(vinfo->dwProductVersionMS),
    (int) HIWORD(vinfo->dwProductVersionLS));
free(path);
free(ver);
```

Comment: This is probably as good as you can do, but there's no perfect future-proofing for this kind of thing.  If you have a decent automatic update system, future-proofing shouldn't be too big of a problem; alternatively, part of all of your analytics system can be downloaded on-the-fly.  (Just make sure you verify the digital signature.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston: If I had an auto-update system, I would just update the application manifest, so downloading an analytics DLL would be unnecessary.

Comment: Future proofing is not really fiesible, because who can predict what the future will hold.  Who would have thought that `GetVersionEx()` would ever stop working? Who would have ever thought new version APIs would deprecate it?  You have to update your software when change happens.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Don't misrepresent the question: I was never asking for a system that was 100% future proof for all eternity.  And you tell me that I "have to update [my] software"... well, I don't, and you don't know anything about my software so I'm confused as to why you think I'm wrong about this.  I'm just looking for an API that **maybe** will report the correct version on Windows 9.  The `GetVersionEx()` function is practically guaranteed to **not** work on Windows 9 without delivering applications with updated manifests.  This is the specific technical problem I want solved, nothing else.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: downloading the analytics code is one *alternative* to having an auto-update system.  It's significantly easier to implement than a fully fledged auto-update.  Of course it's easier still to assume that the current approach will keep working, and as far as Windows 9 goes it very probably will, so whether it is worth the effort to implement something stronger depends entirely on how important it is to you that it keep working.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: Windows is *backwards* compatible, not necessarily *forwards* compatible. When Windows 9 arrives, why is it so difficult to deliver a manifest update to support Windows 9? Starting with Windows 7, a manifest must be used to explicitly state the OS versions that the app is known to support. If you have not even tested the app on Windows 9 yet, how can it reliably support Windows 9? So the manifest will say that Windows 8 is the last known supported OS version, and Windows 9 will downgrade the app experience as needed to match Windows 8 expectations...

Comment: @DietrichEpp: ..., then, once you have tested the app on Windows 9, you deliver a new manifest that says Windows 9 is supported.  This is also why there is no API to explicitly retrieve the OS's *true* version number anymore.  If an app does not support Windows 9+ yet, but gets a Windows 9+ version number, it can freak out because people abuse version numbers the wrong way (not saying that YOU do, mind you).  Windows is trying to protect you, and you are trying to circumvent that protection.  Hence the need for a hack to get the true version number, like the MSDN documentation describes.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: It is far, far easier just to use the forty lines of code above, rather than maintain the infrastructure required to deliver analytics in a separate DLL which is downloaded.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: The behavior you describe, in fact, is exactly the behavior I want.  I test an application on Windows 8.1, put the Windows 8.1 GUID in the manifest, and when Windows 9 is released, it may run the app in some compatibility layer or something.  I can grab a copy of my application binary and QA it, that's easy, I don't have to go through the whole release process.  It's running fine with the Windows 8.1 manifest, and users can keep running the same binary.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I really do understand why `GetVersionEx()` works the way it does, I'm not really complaining about that.  I'm just trying to solve a technical problem.  "Hence the need for a hack"... well, the reason I asked this question in the first place is because I didn't know how to solve this technical problem I had.  I think it's quite reasonable not to want to deliver new binaries to users just to get an accurate version number in the analytics database.  If that's the only benefit, I'm not going to bother releasing a new version of my application.  These 40 lines solve that problem.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: yes, of course it's easier, it just isn't as robust.  Given the scenario as you've clarified it, you don't need that level of robustness, so I agree that the solution described in this answer is fine *for you*.  Future readers may have different needs, though, so I think it is important to make the limitations of this approach clear.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: I do understand wanting to obtain the true OS version for reporting/analytics purposes.  My company's apps do that.  So I am glad you brought up this issue.  I will keep it in mind moving forward (we haven't embraced Win8 yet).

Answer (score 8):

Yikes, the currently accepted answer is over-complicated. Here's how to get the version of the current windows (with build numbers) quickly and reliably without requiring manifests and other nonsense tricks. And works on Windows 2000 and newer (i.e. every version of Windows in existence).

**Short answer: use [RtlGetVersion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-rtlgetversion).**

Don't have the Windows Driver Development Kit? Then it's a little less simple than including the header and using the function. Here's how you do it both with and without the WDK.

With WDK, include:

```
// Required for RtlGetVersion()
#pragma comment(lib, "ntdll.lib")

#include <Ntddk.h>
```

Without WDK, include:

```
// Required for RtlGetVersion()
#pragma comment(lib, "ntdll.lib")

// Define the function because we don't have the driver development
// kit headers. We could probably acquire them but it makes development
// onboarding a pain in the ass for new employees.
extern "C" {
typedef LONG NTSTATUS, *PNTSTATUS;
#define STATUS_SUCCESS (0x00000000)

// Windows 2000 and newer
NTSYSAPI NTSTATUS NTAPI RtlGetVersion(PRTL_OSVERSIONINFOEXW lpVersionInformation);
}
```

Now, simply get the accurate version details:

```
RTL_OSVERSIONINFOEXW osVers;
osVers.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(osVers);

// fill the structure with version details
NTSTATUS status = RtlGetVersion(&osVers);

// this should always succeed
assert(status == STATUS_SUCCESS);
```

The `osVers` variable now contains the accurate major, minor, and build number. No need to read file versions and no need to dynamically load libraries at runtime.

***Please vote this above the other answer*** so this correct code can be used in applications rather than the rube-goldberg other answer. Thanks.