# What's the supportedOS GUID for Windows 10?

Tags: c#, winapi, .net-4.0, windows-10

We're detecting the OS version for statistics. Starting with Windows 8.1, [the OS "lies" about its version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn481241(v=vs.85).aspx#base.version_helper_apis) when using `GetVersion`. However, `System.Environment.OSVersion` [still calls this API](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/environment.cs) as of .NET 4.5.1. As such, we've added [8.1's GUID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn481241(v=vs.85).aspx#base.version_helper_apis) to the manifest, which works great.

Now, I'd like to prepare the same for Windows 10. Is the GUID for this known yet?

(edit) P/Invoking VerSetConditionMask and VerifyVersionInfo to check for 6.4 or greater does appear to work.

Comment: For a better approach when collecting statistics, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/25986612/886887

Comment: While that would probably work, it seems quite a dirty hack, and would also mean that the app doesn't assert compatibility with the new OS to Program Compatibility Assistant.

Comment: If it was known, it would be subject to change.

Comment: It's the documented method.  Also, you probably shouldn't tell the PCA that your application is compatible with Windows 10 when you haven't actually tested it yet. :-)

Comment: "If it was known, it would be subject to change." — true, but the whole point for developer previews is to be able to prepare in time.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
<!-- This Id value indicates the application supports Windows Threshold functionality-->
<supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}"/>
```

Source: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/07cbfc3a-bced-45b7-80d2-a9d32a7c95d4/supportedos-manifest-for-windows-10?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues

Comment: See [Manifest Madness](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/09/10/manifest-madness.aspx).

Comment: [New link "Manifest Madness"](https://walbourn.github.io/manifest-madness/) (perhaps someone can fix up the above comment and remove mine?)

Answer (score 9):

Other GUIDs for other OS contexts:

| OS | GetVersionEx | supportedOS Id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Windows 11 | *not tested* | <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}"/> *([same as Windows 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sbscs/application-manifests))* |
| Windows 10 | 10.0† (6.4 prior to build 9926) | <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}"/> |
| Windows 8.1 | 6.3 | <supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}"/> |
| Windows 8 | 6.2 | <supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}"/> |
| Windows 7 | 6.1 | <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/> |
| Windows Vista | 6.0 | <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"/> |
| Windows XP | 5.1 | n/a |
| Windows 2000 | 5.0 | n/a |
| Windows NT 4 | 4.0 | n/a |
| Windows NT 3.51 | 3.51 | n/a |
| Windows NT 3.1 | 3.1 | n/a |

† was version 6.4 prior to build 9926. It reports 10.0 after build 9926 (23 January 2015).

The page that maintains the documentation for these values:

- [Application Manifests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sbscs/application-manifests) <sup>*[archive](https://archive.today/k6nPu)*</sup>

## OS Contexts

When running on Windows 10 under a particular OS context, the versions returned are:

| OS Context | GetVersionEx |
| --- | --- |
| Windows Vista | 6.2 |
| Windows 7 | 6.2 |
| Windows 8 | 6.2 |
| Windows 8.1 | 6.3 |
| Windows 10 | 10.0 (6.4 prior to build 9926) |

Comment: For Windows 10 `GetVersionEx`  returns `10.0` not `6.4`. see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Microsoft_Windows_versions

Comment: UP TO DATE INFO: It looks like Window 11 uses the same guid as Win 10, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sbscs/application-manifests?redirectedfrom=MSDN