# After Installation of my msi Osversion Info does not detect OS correctly

Tags: c#, wix, operating-system, windows-10

I have been working on an application which works depending on the Operating System. I have written code of detecting OS version it works correctly when i run application in VS2013, it correctly detect windows 10 OS. But same code when i deploy and create an MSI and install that in windows 10 it detects OS as windows 7 even though i am installing that MSI in windows 10.

I am creating installer in Wix don't know what i am missing.

Comment: Is your code running in an exe that list any supportedOs items in its manifest? If so, do you include the Windows 10 GUID?

Comment: Nope i haven't added any manifest file in to my project. Do i need to add that if yes can you please explain more on this.

Comment: https://www.google.com/#q=supportedos+windows+10 yields, among other things, http://stackoverflow.com/q/26151534/89999