# Embedding manifest into the application binary breaks OpenGL 2

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, manifest

My application uses OpenGL. Everything worked until today, when I embedded the following manifest into the .exe. I need it for the sole purpose of being able to get the current OS version with the `isWindowsNOrGreater` functions, which are capped at Windows 8 (not even 8.1) unless the application has explicitly specified support for Windows 8.1 and/or 10:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> 
<assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <assemblyIdentity 
        type="win32" 
        name="com.my.Test"
        version="1.0.0.0" 
    />
    <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1"> 
        <application> 
            <!-- Windows 10 --> 
            <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}"/>
            <!-- Windows 8.1 -->
            <supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}"/>
            <!-- Windows Vista -->
            <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"/> 
            <!-- Windows 7 -->
            <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>
            <!-- Windows 8 -->
            <supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}"/>
        </application> 
    </compatibility>
</assembly>
```

As soon as I embed this manifest, I can no longer initialize OpenGL 2: `wglGetProcAddress("wglCreateContextAttribsARB")` returns null, and `glGetString(GL_RENDERER)` returns the dreaded "GDI Generic" instead of the actual hardware renderer.

What's going on, why does the manifest break OpenGL, and how I can I fix this?

Comment: Out of morbid curiosity, I googled a bit, and this problem seems to affect others too, e.g.: https://community.roonlabs.com/t/opengl-error-after-upgrade-to-1-1/3266/18 or https://forum.xojo.com/24477-windows-10-manifest-gotcha/0 or http://forum.drdteam.org/viewtopic.php?f=24&t=6696 Do you have an Intel onboard GPU, too?

Comment: @ThorngardSO: I couldn't find any solutions, though. And yes, my dev machine runs the Intel integrated graphics as well.

Comment: Yes, it may indeed be that you are screwed at this point. The way I understood it is that the manifest will alter the results some Win-API calls for everyone living in your application process. So the Intel driver (or the part of the driver-dll that resides in your process) is affected by this too, and -- due to its buggy implementation -- fails. No idea how anyone but Intel can fix this. Let us know if you find something, though!

Comment: @ThorngardSO, ah, now it makes sense to me! Wouldn't expect from a top company like Intel to not patch such a bug by now. Well, I've implemented a temporary workaround for my `GetVersionEx` problem and removed the manifest, but it's not pretty.

Comment: If you just want to report the version number, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25986331/how-to-determine-windows-version-in-future-proof-way

Comment: @DietrichEpp: Interesting! Didn't see that particular solution. I went a different way - `RtlGetVersion`. Not sure how good an idea it is to call kernel-mode function from user-mode code, though.