# GetVersionEx with manifestation Windows 10 and integrated GPU

Tags: windows, manifest

I have OpengL application and using GetVersionEx to get the OS with adding a compatibility manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="application" version="1.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="*"/>
    <description>app.exe</description>
    <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <security>
            <requestedPrivileges>
                <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"/>
            </requestedPrivileges>
        </security>
    </trustInfo>
    <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
        <application>
            <!-- Windows 10 -->
            <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}"/>

            <!-- Windows 8.1 -->
            <supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}"/>

            <!-- Windows 8 -->
            <supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}"/>

            <!-- Windows 7 -->
            <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>

            <!-- Windows Vista -->
            <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"/>
        </application>
    </compatibility>
    <application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <windowsSettings>
            <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware>
        </windowsSettings>
    </application>
</assembly>
```

Some of my users who have a laptop Windows 10 with integrated GPU Intel HD Grapchis get into trouble.
Somehow OpenGL won't use Intel HD Grapchis as a render, but instead uses GDI Generic.
My investigation showed that if I delete the GUID from the compatibility manifest for Windows 10, the render Intel HD Grapchis will be used.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possibly related: [Embedding manifest into the application binary breaks OpenGL 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34676697/embedding-manifest-into-the-application-binary-breaks-opengl-2)

Comment: Yes, it looks like it.